# queue - how to detect a specific item has been dequeued?

Tags: python, asynchronous, queue

Is there a way - builtin or otherwise - to detect that a specific item has been dequeued?

Let's say that I only want to perform an action AFTER I know that `itemX` has been dequeued.

```
q = queue.Queue()
q.put(itemX)
# Now I want to block-wait or get a callback or poll when `itemX` has been dequeued
```

How would I set up that callback/block-wait/poll?

Answer (score 0):

Well, since a queue is not restricted to accommodating unique values, you will need to find a way to uniquely tag every entry into your queue to make them distinct. This seems to be the only viable way of keeping track of your queue and grab ItemX when it leaves the queue

Comment: Yes I was thinking something like `q.put((itemX, synch_obj_itemX))` and then the dequeuer would be responsible for triggering `synch_obj_itemX`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: You might want to elaborate what you are trying to get done to better give insight into this

Comment: I think my question is defined well enough to be useful: the producer wants to know when a consumer of the queue has dequeued a particular item.

Answer (score 0):

Queues were not specifically designed with that functionality in mind, but if it fits your use case you can do something like that with a one-element queue:

```
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue
import time

N = 5

def f(q):
    for i in range(N):
        print('t2: waiting for element from t1...')
        time.sleep(1)
        i = q.get()
        print('t2: got {}...'.format(i))

q = Queue(1)
t = Thread(target=f, args=(q,))
t.start()
for i in range(N):
    print('t1: putting item {}.'.format(i))
    q.put(i)
    q.put(None)
    q.get()
    print('t1: t2 got element, continuing')

t.join()

print('done')
```

Output:

```
t2: waiting for element from t1...
t1: putting item 0.
t2: got 0...
t2: waiting for element from t1...
t1: t2 got element, continuing
t1: putting item 1.
t2: got 1...
t2: waiting for element from t1...
t1: t2 got element, continuing
t1: putting item 2.
t2: got 2...
t2: waiting for element from t1...t1: t2 got element, continuing

t1: putting item 3.
t2: got 3...
t2: waiting for element from t1...
t1: t2 got element, continuing
t1: putting item 4.
t2: got 4...t1: t2 got element, continuing

done
```

It's not completely sure, though, it relies on the consumer thread not running `q.get()` between the `q.put(None)` and `q.get()` of the producer thread.

Comment: This doesn't provide a way to `callback/block-wait/poll` as I stated in my question

Comment: @Adrian In the example, the main thread blocks in `q.put(None)` until the second thread runs `i = q.get()`. In this case it works because the second thread sleeps later, so the main thread always has the chance to do `q.get()` before the second thread tries to get from the queue again, but as I said it is not a safe method.

Comment: I would prefer a way to block/poll/callback for a specific item that I queued. I think I know what to do.